# Yii2 Filtering CRUD and Dropdown menu

Tags: php, mysql, yii, yii2

I'm trying to learn the Yii2 Framework. Could someone please help me with this, I really appreciate it. Getting stuck at 2 things, filtering the data in the CRUD and add a dropdown menu at (' reserveringen) on the navigation bar.     [Image database names](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6xDLO.png) Tafel = Table (translated)

```
  [Image database names][1]
    
    
    
    
    







<?php

/* @var $this \yii\web\View */
/* @var $content string */

use app\widgets\Alert;
use yii\helpers\Html;
use yii\bootstrap\Nav;
use yii\bootstrap\NavBar;
use yii\widgets\Breadcrumbs;
use app\assets\AppAsset;

AppAsset::register($this);
?>
<?php $this->beginPage() ?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="<?= Yii::$app->language ?>">
<head>
    <meta charset="<?= Yii::$app->charset ?>">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <?php $this->registerCsrfMetaTags() ?>
    <title><?= Html::encode($this->title) ?></title>
    <?php $this->head() ?>
</head>
<body>
<?php $this->beginBody() ?>

<div class="wrap">
    <?php
    NavBar::begin([
        'brandLabel' => Yii::$app->name,
        'brandUrl' => Yii::$app->homeUrl,
        'options' => [
            'class' => 'my-navbar navbar-fixed-top',
            
        ],
    ]);
    echo Nav::widget([
        'options' => ['class' => 'navbar-nav navbar-right'],
        'items' => [
            ['label' => 'Home', 'url' => ['/site/index']],
          
            
            
            ['label' => 'Serveren', 'url' => ['/overzicht/index' ]],

               [
                  'label' => 'Reserveringen',
                   'items' => [
                   ['label' => 'Reservering weergeven', 'url' => '/reserveringen/index'],
                   ['label' => 'Reservering maken', 'url' => '/reserveringen/create'],
                             ],
                            

            ['label' => 'Gegevens', 'url' => ['/eten/index' ]],    
           // ['label' => 'About', 'url' => ['/site/about']],
           // ['label' => 'Contact', 'url' => ['/site/contact']],
            Yii::$app->user->isGuest ? (
                ['label' => 'Login', 'url' => ['/site/login']]
           ) : (
            '<li>'
               . Html::beginForm(['/site/logout'], 'post')
               . Html::submitButton(
                   'Logout (' . Yii::$app->user->identity->username . ')',
                   ['class' => 'btn btn-link logout']
               )
              . Html::endForm()
                . '</li>'
            )
        ],
    ]);
    NavBar::end();
    ?>

    <div class="container">
        <?= Breadcrumbs::widget([
            'links' => isset($this->params['breadcrumbs']) ? $this->params['breadcrumbs'] : [],
        ]) ?>
        <?= Alert::widget() ?>
        <?= $content ?>
    </div>
</div>

<footer class="footer">
    <div class="container">
        
 <!-- <p class="pull-right"><?= Yii::powered() ?></p> -->
    </div>
</footer>

<?php $this->endBody() ?>
</body>
</html>
<?php $this->endPage() ?>
Another thing I'm stuck at is the option to filter the CRUD by selecting a data Trying to make a select option where the person can filter the table number. 1 to 5. For example when 1 is selected only the datas with table 1 appear.
```

Another thing I'm stuck at is the option to filter the CRUD by selecting a data Trying to make a select option where the person can filter the table number. 1 to 5. For example when 1 is selected only the datas with table 1 appear.

```
    <?php

use yii\helpers\Html;
use yii\grid\GridView;

/* @var $this yii\web\View */
/* @var $searchModel app\models\bestellingSearch */
/* @var $dataProvider yii\data\ActiveDataProvider */

$this->title = 'Bestelling maken';
$this->params['breadcrumbs'][] = $this->title;
?>
<div class="bestelling-index">

    <h1><?= Html::encode($this->title) ?></h1>

    <p>
        <?= Html::a('Maak een bestelling aan', ['create'], ['class' => 'btn btn-success']) ?>
    </p>

    <?php $menuSort=[1=>'1' ,2=>'2' ,3=>'3' ,4=>'4' ,5=>'5'];
    ?>

    <?php // echo $this->render('_search', ['model' => $searchModel]); ?>

    <?= GridView::widget([
        'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
        'filterModel' => $searchModel,
        'columns' => [
            ['class' => 'yii\grid\SerialColumn'],

            'ID',
            'Artikel:ntext',
            'Table',

            [
                'attribute'=>'Table',
                'label' => 'Table',
                'filter'=>$menuSort,
                'contentOptions' => ['style' => 'width:200px; white-space: normal;' ],
                'format' => 'raw',
                'value' => function ($model) use ($menuSort) { return $menuSort[$model->type];}
             ],

           

            //   'filter'=>$menuSoorten,
            'Prijs',
            'Totaal',

            ['class' => 'yii\grid\ActionColumn'],
        ],
    ]); ?>


</div>


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/PT8Qu.png
```

Comment: You forgot to ask the question :P. What is your problem with that code?